# Why won't .selectedIndex return a value for the choice?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, plotly

I am trying to change the plot type for my Plotly JS code but it wont return a vale for the btn.selectedIndex.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('change', () => {
  var sel = btn.selectedIndex
  if (sel == 1) {
    data1['type'] = "markers",
      data1['mode'] = "scatter"
  } else if (sel == 2) {
    data1['type'] = "bar"
  }
})
```

```html
<select name="Plot Type" id="btn">
  <option value="">--Choose Plot--</option>
  <option value="">--markers--</option>
  <option value="">--bar--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should bind to the change event and not click.

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: Are you certain the thing you're getting errors about `sel` being not defined? Might it be that `data1` is what's actually undefined?

Comment: So I just made some changes to the code where I followed the thing that @espascarello mentioned. I am not getting any error messages, but the if else statements are being skipped.. It doesn't return the index of the selection.

Comment: @Daniel Beck, data1 is defined I just didn't add in the question. I know Data1 is defined because I get a plot when I run "Plotly.newPlot".

Comment: "It doesn't return the index of the selection." Your function doesn't try to return anything, so that isn't surprising. But if you `console.log(sel)` right after defining it you will see that the value is set correctly to the selectedIndex.    It's not skipping your if statements, they're just not doing anything visible.

Comment: Your code works when data1 is defined so you have a problem that is related to something you are not showing us. My guess is you have mutliple elements with the id btn and what you think is the select is some other element.

Comment: Awesome you were correct! @Daniel Beck. The charts are changing now.